# How to send POST request to Flask API employing CSRF token from mobile device (android) app?

Tags: python, android, flask, csrf

**Question:**

How can I POST data from my android app to my flask web app which is employing CSRF protection?

**Background:**
I've built a website using Flask, and have protected it from CSRF attacks by globally deploying CSRFProtect(), which comes from the Flask-WTForms package.

I am building a phone app that will allow a user to automatically send data to their account on the Flask database every day.

I can successfully access the Flask API using a GET request from my android app.
I am unable to successfully send a POST request from my android app, unless I turn off global CSRF protection within my Flask API.

**My thoughts so far:**
**Option one** - turn off CSRF protection if request is coming from an application.
From reading I understand that CSRF attacks require cookies, which are only generated by browsers, and thus if my request is coming from my app, then I am safe from CSRF attacks and could turn off CSRF protection for a specific URL. **BUT**, this URL could be accessed by anyone if they were to discover it, so I would need to keep CSRF protection on if the request was coming from a browser, and turn it off if coming from my android app. Is this possible?

**Option two** - get the CSRF token on my android app.
I don't think that coding the token into my app would be safe, as anyone would be able to download the app and potentially access the code (right?). If that's true, then I would need to somehow get the token from Flask via an authentication process with the Flask app. **BUT**, how can I send form data to the flask app if CSRF protection is blocking my POST requests?

Please advise. Normally with enough googling I can figure out an answer, but on this I'm stuck!
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your assumptions about CSRF are incorrect. CSRF is not a cookie and CSRF is not a single secret value. The secret configured in the app is not the CSRF value used to protect forms.

Comment: Hi VPfB, thanks for your response. Even though my understanding of CSRF is incorrect, do you have any suggestions on how I can POST data from my android app to my flask web app if it is using CSRF?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Normally, a client GETs a form from the server. Inside that form is a hidden field with some CSRF value. Then the client fills-in required fields and POSTs the whole form including the hidden CSRF field to the server. The server compares the CSRF it has sent with the CSRF just received to verify that the form is coming from the client it communicates with. Without adding more details we cannot know what went wrong.

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot of sense. I was attempting to POST from my android app to my Flask app, without having first requested (GET) a form from my server. Thus, the POST request was failing because no CSRF token was being returned to my server for verification. I need to use a GET request to receive a form, with the hidden field containing the CSRF token, which I can then POST back to my flask app.

Now that I have a direction I will keep working on this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information here, but I faced a similar issue when I started learning about flask. So, I think this should be a similar case for you too.

I was creating a simple webhook that would accept POST requests from another application. If I turned CSRF off, POST requests would work, but with CSRF protection turned on, POST requests returned with a 400 status code.

There is a simple way to exempt any views or blueprints in Flask from CSRF protection. We can decorate the route that does not need the csrf protection with a flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFProtect.exempt decorator. Please look at the
below code.

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__) # this will take name of the project
csrf = CSRFProtect()
csrf.init_app(app)

@app.route@app.route("/newhook", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@csrf.exempt #this will exempt the csrf for this view
def newhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        alldata = request.get_json()
        resp = alldata['message']
        num = alldata["from"]
        myres = make_response(jsonify(resp, num))
        
        return myres
```

I am also providing a link to the official flask_wtf CSRF protect documentation below for reference.
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/csrf/#exclude-views-from-protection

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

you can sent it using like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```